# PetitParser: How to match to token set

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, petitparser

In PetitParser2, how do I match a closed set of tokens, like month names? E.g. (in pseudocode) 
`[ :word | MonthNames anySatisfy: [ :mn | mn beginsWith: word ] ] asParser.`

`PPPredicateSequenceParser` seemed like a possibility, but it seems you have to know the string size in advance. I guess I could just do something like:

```
| monthRules |
    monthRules := Array streamContents: [ :unamused: |
        MonthNames collect: [ :e | 
            s nextPut: e asString asPParser.
            s nextPut: (e first: 3) asPParser ] ].
    ^ PP2ChoiceNode withAll: monthRules
```

But I was wondering if there was something built in/straightforward

Answer (score 3):

Other, more clumsy and less efficient option is to use a custom block:

```
[ :context | 
    | position names |
    names := #('January' 'February' 'March' 'April').   
    position := context position.
    names do: [ :name | 
        (context next: name size) = name ifTrue: [  
            ^ name
        ] ifFalse: [ 
            context position: position
        ]
    ].
    ^ PP2Failure new
] asPParser parse: 'April'
```

I would not recommend this though, because PP2 does not know anything about the block and cannot apply any optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use a parser for each element in the set:

```
monthsParser := 'January' asPParser / 
                'February' asPParser / 
                'March' asPParser.
monthsParser parse: 'January'
```

Alternatively, creating a choice parser from a collection:

```
names := #('January' 'February' 'March' 'April').
monthsParser := PP2ChoiceNode withAll: (names collect: [ :l | 
                    l asPParser ]).
monthsParser parse: 'January'
```

The "optimization" of PP2 should choose the right alternative pretty quickly.

Comment: Does this fit your need or is there something I missed?

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up with in the second half of my question, but I was wondering if there's something in-built to "match input of unknown length against an arbitrary block". Thinking more, I guess it'd be pretty inefficient because it would have to consider the entire input, but still curious. If it could be done, maybe one could pass a max input size instead of a fixed input size...

Comment: I see, unfortunatelly, there is nothing like this in PP2 now. I can imagine we could transfrom set of tokens to deterministic finite state automaton to recognize a tokens in a set of tokens in linear time. It would get better performance compared to the choice of of literal tokens (as I suggested).